# New to SP - How can I do this in one/multiple lists

Tags: list-form

Disclaimer - I do not have access to Designer - so working within the browser right now. If I HAVE to get it, I will request it but the manager of that team is a pain.

- Application List

  - Application Name
  - Analyst
  - AppNumber(If Needed)
- Known Issues List

  - Application Name (or AppNumber if needed for reference)
  - Problem
  - Solution,
  - User who singed off.
- New Issues

  - Application Name (Or App Number)
  - New Problem
  - Troubleshooting Discussion
  - Solution
  - Resolved (Boolean).

The part I cant do, is tie these together into One Form. Ideally, the form would be like below.

- App Name - Short Text
  Analyst - User Lookup
- Known Issues - Large Text field that has a LINK? to each Problem related to this Application--- OR the form shows two columns of Problem - Solution.
- Current Issues -- List the same way, but for unresolved issues with no solution.
  Button to create a new Issue for the Application the form is opened for.

I am new to SharePoint other than building a simple list, or taking care of permissions for our team site, so I apologize if this is not explained right.

Can you please include a link to any advanced form stuff or if I need designer a link to newb guide for it?

Thanks a TON for any and all help!

Bill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not have access to development tools, start with a simple method.

Create three lists:

- Application List

  - Application Name (title field)
  - Analyst (person field)
- Known Issues List

  - Application (lookup field referencing App list)
  - Problem (multiline field)
  - Solution (multiline field)
  - User who singed off (person field)
- New Issues List

  - Application (lookup field referencing App list)
  - New Problem (multiline field)
  - Troubleshooting Discussion (multiline field)
  - Solution (multiline field)
  - Resolved (yes/no field).

Then create a **Web Part Page** and insert three webparts in the page
- App List (first web parte)
- Known Issues List
- New Issues List

In this page connect the first webpart with both others. To do this you must use the connection between webparts that helps you to do something like a master-detail. More info here:

[Creating Connected Web parts in SharePoint](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rajbugga/2013/04/25/creating-connected-web-parts-in-sharepoint/)

[Connect data in Web Parts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-data-in-Web-Parts-54a36fda-019c-49b3-ad33-0cd94bf70c1e)

This is the easiest way to get started. The important thing is to create the lookup fields well. And connect the webparts. It is far from being a traditional display of master detail. But the advantage is that you do not need to code anything.

Then, if you dare to add code in JavaScrit, it can be improved.
And if you can use C #, too.

Comment: Thank You SO MUCH, that is exactly the instruction I was seeking!